# Checking if the end of each line in the file is ending with a letter followed by 8 digits number

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a problem with checking if each line of my files is ending with a letter `(A-Z (always capital))`followed by exatcly 8 digit numbers (doesnt matter which one). So I have a number of files and content of each file looks like this:

```
Nc1nc2cc3OCCOc3cc2s1 A10000001          
CCN(CC)C1CCN(Cc2cc(I)cc(I)c2O)CC1 B100000002
CCN(CC)C1CCN(Cc2cc(cc(I)c2O)C#CCO)CC1 C10000003
```

There is always a space between this "string" and letter wtih numbers. So, in this example `B100000002` there are 9 digits after letter. Since I done most of the things manually I would like to check if in my files there are errors. Can anybody help me with some bash command so I can see which lines have different, incorrect pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep` to get the lines that don't follow the rule:

```
grep -v ' [[:upper:]][0-9]\{8\}$' file*
```

- space matches itself
- `[[:upper:]]` is matched by any uppercase letter
- `[0-9]` matches a digit
- `\{8\}` is a "quantifier", it means the preceding construct must be repeated 8 times
- `$` matches at the end of line
- `-v` shows the lines that are *not* matched

Comment: "...get the lines that don't follow the rule" ? Wouldn't that also need `-v` flag for `grep -v` to match lines that don't follow the pattern ?

Comment: you are right, when I add `-v` then script applies to all lines, without it, it just greps some of them..

Answer (score 0):

you could grep with a perl regexp:

```
grep -P ' [a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{8}$'
```

`-P` : for perl Regular expression

: the regexp starts with a space, because you want a space before the uppercase letter

`[a-zA-Z]{1}` : Exactly 1 alphbaetic char lowercase or uppercase (you can remove a-z for uppercase only ie [A-Z]{1})

`[0-9]{8}` : exactly 8 numeric chars

`$` : end of line

If you want to display the lines that does not match the pattern, just add the `-v` option to the grep command.

If you want to display lines numbers, add the `-n` option.

```
grep -Pvn ' [a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{8}$'
```